# How do I get ubuntu to reconfigure /etc/network/interfaces for me?

Tags: networking, ubuntu, configuration

How do I get Ubuntu to figure out the interfaces available on my computer and generate a new `/etc/network/interfaces` file? It created it the first time so I know it can somehow.

Is there something like `dpkg-reconfigure <what?>` that would just recheck for me?

Comment: What would you want this for?

Comment: I'm +1-ing this question because we need non-linux people to be able to configure networks for our appliance. Something e.g. curses based that makes it __easy__ is what I'm looking for...

Answer (score 4):

in ubuntu 14.04.1 THIS happens if you **clone** a system to other hardware as /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules contains MAC address's of ethernet hardware on the source computer.

YES - just deleting /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules allows things to be refreshed to a working state at reboot.

Comment: Only true if using the legacy `eth0` style network names. With the new 'predictable network interface names' introduced around ubuntu15.10 the 70-perisistent-net.rules trick no longer applies.

Answer (score 1):

Try run below command

```
dpkg-reconfigure ifupdown
```

possibly.

However, you are probably running into an issue with udev.  If you have rebooted, and eth0 disappeared:

```
ifconfig -a
```

you can mv/rm the file in /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules and reboot, and your primary ethernet card should become eth0 again.

This would happen if you switched motherboards/network cards.

Answer (score 1):

/etc/network/interfaces is generated by the actual installer, not any of the packages on your system:

```
opus:~ broder$ dpkg -S /etc/network/interfaces
dpkg: /etc/network/interfaces not found.
```

Because it's not managed by any particular package, no package is going to modify the file.

If you want to add new interfaces to /etc/network/interfaces, you have to do that manually. Alternatively, if you want your network interfaces to be managed automatically by your system, I believe the official answer at this point is to use NetworkManager. NetworkManager will handle configuration for any network interface that's *not* listed in /etc/network/interfaces.